# Printing right-to-left in booklet format

Tags: printing, pdf, rtl

I have a RTL (right-to-left) pdf document and want to print it in booklet format so that it could be printed double sided and binded as a book.
There is simple solutions for LTR (left-to-right) documents, such as `pdfbook`:

```
pdfbook inputfile.pdf
```

above simple command will create a new pdf file named `inputfile-book.pdf` that could be printed double sided (duples printed "Long edge").

Is there a similar solution for right to left documents?

Answer (score 2):

I foungI found a wokaround for this problem:

for **16 pages** input file:

```
pdfbook --signature* 4 inputfile.pdf 16,15,14,13,6,5,8,7,10,9,12,11,4,3,2,1 --outfile book-RTL.pdf
```

for **14 pages** input file:

```
pdfbook --signature* 4 inputfile.pdf {},{},14,13,6,5,8,7,10,9,12,11,4,3,2,1 --outfile book-RTL.pdf
```

for **12 pages** input file:

```
pdfbook --signature* 4 inputfile.pdf 12,11,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,2,1 --outfile book-RTL.pdf
```

for **10 pages** input file:

```
pdfbook --signature* 4 inputfile.pdf {},{},4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,2,1 --outfile book-RTL.pdf
```

for **8 pages** input file:

```
pdfbook --signature* 4 inputfile.pdf 2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7 --outfile book-RTL.pdf
```

Comment: this was very useful, but in order to get it to print the booklet RTL, I had to remove the asterisk after --signature. Also, where can I find more information about the number order that you used.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Learner's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038361/21794) worked, but I looked for another solution for several reasons. [These reasons include: [pdfbook is no longer officially supported by the developers](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam-extras); I had to remove the asterisk in the signature switch in order to get it to do RTL; The workarounds given in that answer were only for specific numbered booklets, and I couldn't figure out how the numbering system worked, to extrapolate to other sized booklets]

Here's the solution using `pdfjam`:

`pdfjam --booklet 'true' --paper 'letter' --suffix 'book' --landscape  --signature* '4' 'inputfile.pdf' --outfile ./`

To break down the command:

`pdfjam` == `pdfjam is the engine behind the pdfbook script (pdfjam itself is a shell-script interface to the "pdfpages" LaTeX package)`

`--booklet 'true'` == `this is what makes pdfjam print the pdf as a booklet, as opposed to all the pages in order` (this is [a key value for '\includepdfmerge', in the LaTeX 'pdfpages' package](https://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf))

`--paper 'letter'` == `pdfjam uses A4 by default, this will tell it to use 8.5x11 size paper`

`--suffix 'book'` == `this will automatically add the suffix '-book.pdf' to the inputfile name to create the output file name. In order for this to work, the output file must be a directory`

`--landscape` == `make the booklet go along the long side of the page`

`--signature* '4'` == `4 pages on a single doublesided page. The asterisk reverses the order of the pages, giving an RTL booklet`

`'inputfile.pdf'` == `path to input file`

`--outfile ./` == `when a directory is used, the file name will be $inputfile-book.pdf (since we chose book as the suffix earlier. A regular pdf filename can also be used here.)`